# Get the type of type parameter from a type that has type parameter, in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the messy title. I guess, providing an example make it more clear.

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, value: 'a' },
    { id: 2, value: 'b' },
];

// A will be the type Array<{ id: number, value: string }>
type A = typeof array;
// K will be the type of all the keys of Array type like length, toString, ...
type K = keyof A;
// I wish the below can make T the type { id: number, value: string }
type T = paramof A;
```

I know that the example is bit silly since I can just define an interface like `{ id: number, value: string }` to get `T`. But I am in a situation that something like `paramof` will be very useful. Please imagine that the `array` variable is not on my control.

TypeScript allows us to get the type from a value and to get all the keys from a type. Is there any way to get the type of type parameter from a type that has type parameter, in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript 2.8 you can easily do this for any specific generic type, not just for arrays using conditional types:

```
type A = typeof array;
// Get the generic 
type AParam = A extends Array<infer T> ? T : never;
```

In 2.7 or before you can just index the array to get the type of an item:

```
type A = typeof array;
// Item Of A
type AItem = A[0]
// Or 
type AItem2 = typeof array[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that I can do `type AItem = A[0]` which looks very useful. But for my specific case, I can't apply it because it doesn't have any properties that expose the type parameter.

`infer` looks very useful. I couldn't find any easy document but the PR in the TypeScript repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496 `Unpacked` in the PR message is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ryubro Yes, the unpack type is where my answer draws it's inspiration from, but you will notice that you must know the generic types you are unpacking, you can't unpack a new type unless you explicitly add it to `Unpacked`